# Placing bounding boxes in a video using a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, drawing, bounding-box

I planning to make a gui like to placing bounding boxes in a video file . I have csv file that contains this sort of data.
[example of my csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ1XS.png).So i extracted the frame by using the offset value .when i was placing the bounding boxes in the video they are not placing correctly in the frame after the first frame which is 0. I don't understand whats going on. I am using this script to get the frame number. I am not sure if the frame numbers are correct or not.

```
import pandas as pd
import cv2

def main(video_file, csv_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    df['frame_number'] = (df['offset'] * fps / 1000).astype(int) + 1000
    df.to_csv('new_csv_file.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    video_file = "C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\apq-f1d4039a_cam_1_1657139273497_60_108.mp4"
    csv_file = "C:\\Users\\name\\merged_output_final.csv"
    main(video_file, csv_file)
```

also this is my main script

how i am processing the data

```
def get_color(classId, objectId):
    COLORS = [(255, 0, 0)]
    color = COLORS[int(classId) % len(COLORS)] 
    return color

# Main function

def process_video():
    global CSV_PATH, VIDEO_PATH, OUTPUT_PATH
    THRESHOLD = 0.8
    df = pd.read_csv(CSV_PATH)
    df.sort_values('offset', inplace=True)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_PATH)
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH, 'output.avi'), fourcc, fps, (width, height))
    df_index = 0

    # Skip to the first frame based on the 'offset' value
    target_frame = int(df.iloc[df_index]['offset'] / 1000 * fps)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, target_frame)

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret==True:
            current_timestamp = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
            print(f'Current video timestamp: {current_timestamp}')
            while df_index < len(df) and df.iloc[df_index]['offset'] <= current_timestamp:
                row = df.iloc[df_index]
                
                if row['prob'] >= THRESHOLD:
                    x, y, w, h = row['x'], row['y'], row['w'], row['h']
                    objectId = row['objectId']
                    print(f'Drawing bounding box from CSV row {df_index}: {row}')
                    x1 = int(x * width)
                    y1 = int(y * height)
                    x2 = int((x + w) * width)
                    y2 = int((y + h) * height)

                    frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), get_color(row['classId'], objectId), 2)
                    frame = cv2.putText(frame, str(row['classId']), (x1, y1-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, get_color(row['classId'], objectId), 2)

                df_index += 1
            out.write(frame)
        else:
            break

    cap.release()
    out.release()

    result_label.config(text=f"Processed video saved in {OUTPUT_PATH}")
    print("Processing completed!")
```

I have also added some images of frame number[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7wLA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZljLs.png) for first few frames

So basically I want to know how can I add bbx in the video, what's wrong?